# How to improve guessing game and condense

Tags: python

An issue with my guessing game. When I input the correct value for the guess in order to "win" the game, the loop does not pick up the input correctly and fails to catch the word. Any idea on how to simplify this issue or condense code? (Secret_word shown is only printed so I could easily test using the correct # ) Also, ignore my notes.

```
secret_word = rn.randint(1,20)
guess = ""
guess_count = 0 # how man times the user has guessed
guess_limit = 3 # how many guesses the user has left
out_of_guesses = False # boleean to tell us if they have guesses to keep playing

while guess != secret_word: # as long as they havnt gotten the word and still have guesses
    if guess_count < guess_limit: # this check to see if they have guesses
        if guess_count == 2:
            print("Careful you only have one more guess!")
        print(secret_word)
        print("Failed guesses: " + str(guess_count))
        guess = input("Enter guess: ")
        guess_count += 1

        if guess == secret_word:
            print("Congratulations you win!")

    else: # Guess_COUNT was Not less than guess limit they are out of guesses
        out_of_guesses = True # This turns the switch "on for out of guesses.

if out_of_guesses: # Tackles two outcomes, you win or you lose
    print("Out of guesses, you lose!")
```

Comment: Your secret_word is an integer, the guess is a string. These are never equal, you must convert one of it into the other type before comparing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you had to convert your user input into an integer in order to be able to compare it to your secret word which is actually not a word but an integer.  Also I fixed the logic of out_of_guesses in your code:

```
import random as rn
secret_word= rn.randint(1,20)

guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = True

while guess_count < guess_limit:
    print("Hint:", secret_word)
    print("Failed guesses: " + str(guess_count))

    if guess_count == guess_limit - 1:
        print("Careful you only have one more guess!")

    guess = input("Enter guess: ")

    if int(guess) == secret_word:
        print("Congratulations you win!")
        out_of_guesses = False
        break

    guess_count +=1

if out_of_guesses == True:
    print("Out of guesses, you lose!")
    print("Secret word was", secret_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a integer, a string will not work. So, do

```
guess = ""
try: # user may input not-number value
  guess = int(guess)
except: # user has inputted not-number value
  print("Whoops, you didn’t input a valid number! Try again.")
  exit()
```